# A big man is assumed to be fat, until he takes shirt off. This happens on a remote planet

Tags: story-identification

In a book, written in 90's or earlier, a group of people is sent to a remote planet. This was possibly a punishment for a crime. They were sleeping in the space ship, and they wake up after landing. I don't remember what happened to the ship after that. I think the planet was quite primitive, possibly they were the first people there. They had laser guns.

One of the characters is called fat by others, because he is a big man and wears a loose shirt. Then he fights with someone and takes his shirt off, and the others see he is very athletic.

Comment: Sounds a bit like one of the Dune prequels by Brian Herbert and Kevin J. Anderson. Wasn't it Duncan Idaho who got sent to a distant planet in order to train?

Comment: Note that duplicate target is already the target of another closed duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is Exiles of ColSec by Douglas Hill.

> but he was now revealed to have scarcely a gram of fat on his body. Just hard mounded muscle on chest and back, a flat ridged stomach like armour, the rolling bulge of shoulders and arms

[the excerpt on google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=r4CX31-BbXUC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Fat)

The plot involves a crashed space ship that they live in and they have at least one gun. But as I haven't read it in nearly 30 years my memory is a bit hazy on the details.

Comment: Yes, that's it!